# Relation between a Laravel Command and a Job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Let's say I have a **long-lived process** to run "Backup Database 1"

- I want that to run in every night. (and see result in log)
- Also, I want to run it manually **sometimes** via Artisan Command. (see result in command line)
- Also, I need an html button to run it in my HTML Interface. (see result in screen)

**What's the best approach?**

1. **Should a Job call the Artisan Command?**
2. **Should an Artisan Command call a Job?**
3. **Should both call a third Class?**
4. **Should the html button call a Job and then output the log file?**

***Notes:***

Laravel documentation says you can execute commands in the queue, adding more confusion.

I tried the example, but the --queue option is not automatically implemented

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

```
Artisan::queue('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create the artisan command and make the job call it in your app/Console/Kernel like this:

```
$schedule->command("command_name")->dailyAt("00:00")->thenPing(env("PING_BACKUP_DB"));
```

Use the *ping* part if you're using forge to check that your command is running.

Then create the route you need and run the command you need, [see here from Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

Try  `Artisan:call` instead of queue, you'll see the example if you scroll down a little bit on the link attached